# Paypal button return url to WordPress and display payment informations

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

I have this paypal button:

```
 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

        <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="myPayPalAccount@gmail.com">

        <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

        <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="item-to-buy">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">

        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="mywordpressblog.com/return-url/">


        <!-- Display the payment button. -->
        <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="Pay Now">
        <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >

    </form>
```

How can I get all the payment details in my return url (mywordpressblog.com/return-url/) which is a custom WordPress page?

I need at least to know if payment was successful or not and display a consequent message and make an update on the database.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- mywordpressblog.com/return-url/ --> only redirect to page successful so if you check detail payment after done can use IPN Paypal.
- Document Dev on [Paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) or [other search](https://www.jotform.com/help/276-How-to-Enable-IPN-on-your-Paypal-Account)